# run command with nodejs and get the output with session like : DevTools listening on ws://[::1]:9222/devtools

Tags: node.js, bash, automation, puppeteer, chrome-profile

Here is the command for creating a Chrome profile on the command line.

```
google-chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir="/home/nishant/Nishant system/nishant/nishant_puppeteer" --profile-directory="puppeteer_chrome"
```

When I execute this command on cmd I am able to get output like this:

```
DevTools listening on ws://[::1]:9222/devtools/
```

But when I execute this command using NodeJS, I am not able to get the output as I need to store that output in variable without ending the browser.

Code I tried:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const util = require('util');
// const { spawn } = require('child_process');
// const child_process = require('child_process'); 
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

(async () => {
  
  const child = spawn('',[
    '/bin/sh',
    '-c',
    'google-chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir="/home/nishant/Nishant system/nishant/nishant_puppeteer" --profile-directory="puppeteer_chrome"'
  ]);

  child.stdout.on('data', (chunk) => {
    // data from standard output is here as buffers
    console.log(chunk)
  });

  const browser = await puppeteer.connect(
    { browserWSEndpoint: 'ws://127.0.0.1:9222/devtools/browser/852aa513-077d-4b93-aedd-34ae789be51c'}
    );
  const pages = await browser.pages();
  const page = pages[0];
  await page.goto('https://www.example.com');

  // const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://partners.myntrainfo.com/');
  Rest of your code here
})();
```

Comment: Why not simply launch the browser normally and let Puppeteer manage the socket details? You've tagged this [tag:cmd] but that's for windows, which doesn't match your `/bin/sh`. Please clarify.